# @connection must be on an @model object type field

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I have a small graphQL structure like this for AWS but when I try to push it throws me an error saying

> ✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud
>
> @connection must be on an @model object type field.

Please help to understand where I am making mistakes.

Is there any VS code extension to debug this?

```
type Store {
  id: ID!
  products: [Product] @connection(name: "StoreProducts")
}

type Product @model @searchable {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String!
  price: Float!
  isOnCourse: Boolean!
  isOnOutlet: Boolean!
  store: Store @connection(name: "StoreProducts", sortField: "crearedAt")
  file: S3Object!
}

type S3Object {
  bucket: String!
  region: String!
  key: String!
}

type User
  @model(
    queries: { get: "getUser" }
    mutations: { create: "registredUser", update: "updateUser" }
    subscriptions: null
  ) {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  email: String!
  phoneNumber: String!
  registred: Boolean
  orders: [Order] @connection(name: "UserOrders", sortField: "createdAt")
}

type Order
  @model(
    queries: null
    mutations: { create: "createOrder" }
    subscriptions: null
  ) {
  id: ID!
  product: Product @connection
  user: User @connection(name: "UserOrders")
  orderLocation: OrderLocation
  crearedAt: String
}

type OrderLocation {
  tableNumber: String
  qrData: String
  holeNumber: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a relation on type Product

```
store: Store @connection(name: "StoreProducts", sortField: "crearedAt")
```

You have to tell server how to look for the items. by which field name. That is why you are getting this error "@connection must be on an @model object type field."

Solution would be add `fields`. On type Product if you want to bring Store Products, you need to add "id" fields.

```
store: Store @connection(name: "StoreProducts", fields:["id"] sortField: "crearedAt")
```

In all other types if you want to have relation, you have to define a convenient field to query the data.